# Why is my JSON to XML converter using BOOST Property Tree giving a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, json, boost

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>  
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    ifstream file;
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    file.open ("json.txt");

    if (!file)
        cout << "problem";

    //std::stringstream ss;
    //ss << "{ \"root\": { \"values\": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] } }";
    boost::property_tree::read_json(file, pt);

    ofstream filexml ("xml.txt");

    boost::property_tree::write_xml(filexml, pt);

    cout <<"done";
    return 0;
}
```

However if I use the stringstream, it succeeds. The segmentation fault is at read_json call. The contents of the json.txt file are what is seen in the comments for stringstream. Can you point out what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Don't use `cout << "problem";` but `throw runtime_error("problem");`. For one, `cout` is probably line-buffered, so you don't see the output until you flush the stream or write a newline. Then, there is *NO POINT IN CONTINUING* if opening the file fails. So don't continue but throw.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. I changed it to runtime_error. I see that the file opened successfully. I still see the segFaut.

Comment: May be you have exception in read_json.

try
    {     
        boost::property_tree::read_json(ss, pt); 
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

Comment: How does that segfault look in a *debugger* ?

Comment: @AlexBG: Since when do exceptions cause segmentation faults?

Comment: You need to produce a stack trace from your debugger, but otherwise this is a good question. My instinct here is a silly precondition in `boost::property_tree` that should be handled much better; perhaps there's an open bug for it. But, again, we need more details first.

Comment: Hmm.. How about checking your file's encoding if UTF-8(with BOM) or anything read_json() cannot parse on it?

If your json file was saved as with UTF-8(with BOM) encoding, change it to ANSI and try again.